# Add static prefix to values while recursively traversing a multidimensional array

Tags: php, recursion, multidimensional-array, key

I have the following code

```
$fruits = [
    'sweet' => 'sugar',
    'sour' => 'lemon',
    'myfruits' => [
        'a' => 'apple',
        'b' => 'banana'
    ]
];

function test_alter(&$item1, $key, $prefix){
    print $key;
    print "<br />";
    $item1 = "$key $prefix: $item1";
}


array_walk_recursive($fruits, 'test_alter', 'fruit');
```

When I execute it, I get this

```
sweet<br />sour<br />a<br />b<br />
```

But the expected output is

```
sweet<br />sour<br />myfruits<br />a<br />b<br />
```

So how do I get **`myfruits`** printed there?

Comment: From the manual: ["_Any key that holds an array will not be passed to the function._"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php#:~:text=Any%20key%20that%20holds%20an%20array%20will%20not%20be%20passed%20to%20the%20function.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't with `array_walk_recursive`. You will need to use plain `array_walk` and provide the recursion yourself:

```
function test_alter(&$item1, $key, $prefix) {
    print $key;
    print "<br />";
    if(is_array($item1)) {
        array_walk($item1, 'test_alter', $prefix);
    }
    else {
        $item1 = "$key $prefix: $item1";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't do it with array_walk_recursive(). [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

Try this recursive function.

```
$fruits = array('sweet' => 'sugar', 'sour' => 'lemon', 'myfruits' => array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana'));

function test_alter(&$item1, $key){
  print $key;
  print "<br />";
  // recursive
  if (is_array($item1)) array_walk ($item1, 'test_alter');
}
array_walk ($fruits, 'test_alter');
```